# JavaScript Device Communication

Tags: javascript, bluetooth, serial-port, usb, device

I need to communicate with an already connected (paired) device attached to my computer via JavaScript.

This is a Bluetooth device however it does NOT use 'low power technology' thus is currently inaccessible via WebBluetooth.

Is there any way to communicate with my device using a different method due to the fact that it is already paired with the computer? Maybe as some sort of serial connection?

Targeting support for Google Chrome.

Node.js or anything outside the realm of HTML5/JavaScript/Chrome Specific JavaScript will not be accepted as an answer. WebBluetooth already shows an example however my device does not use Low-Power-Bluetooth..

Comment: I'm guessing you forgot to add the `Node.js` tag?

Comment: I do not want to use Node.js. I want to run this in a browser, embedded into a website. The website would be communicating with a device attached to the browsers computer, not the machine running the site.

Comment: You can't do that. JS running in browsers don't have access to the hardware (disk, peripherals, etc)

Comment: They do under certain circumstances, for example communicating with a Low Power Bluetooth Device you can use WebBluetooth. You can also communicate with attached USB devices using WebUSB. I'm trying to figure out here if there is some other extension I can utilize to communicate with my already connected Bluetooth device. Since it's already connected the browser does not need to pair the device with the machine thus maybe I can treat it as a Serial or USB or some other type of device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use something like NodeJS. Browsers cannot access hardware attached to the computer unless the browser provides an API for it or you have an app on the host machine that the browser communicates with.

I suggest learning NodeJS as it is a great language and considering you already know JS the syntax will be familiar.

Comment: NodeJS sidesteps the question. Are there any other means available using JavaScript? Anything Google Chrome offers, even if it means enabling experimental flags, is okay. I've tried to search myself but someone with more expertise might know exactly how to treat this device (USB/Serial/Other) and an available api.

Comment: @KKlouzal if there was an alternate I would have mentioned it. Chrome does not support this as it would be a huge security flaw.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way. Look into pubnub IoT api for bi-dir nearby device communications:
https://www.pubnub.com/solutions/iot/

This is a solution for multiplayer gaming as well. JS api here:
https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk